# Angularjs form reset

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I have a reset function in angular to clear all the fields in a form. If I do something like:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="resetForm()">reset</a>

$scope.resetForm = function() {
  $scope.someForm = {};
}
```

Everything works fine. But I want to use this function for multiple forms on the site. If I pass the form object in like:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="resetForm(someForm)">reset</a>

$scope.resetForm = function(form) {
  $scope.form = {};
}
```

Then it won't work. Can someone explain to me why this would be happening?

Comment: For a working solution example suggested by Kahn TO:
http://plnkr.co/edit/tR1cd3pFVJxLgPvAplae?p=preview

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

- You're not accessing the passed in variable, still access the `someForm` of current scope.
- When you pass parameter to the function, it's passed by reference. Even when you use `form = {}`, it does not work because it only changes **the reference of the parameter**, not the reference of the passed in `someForm`.

Try:

```
$scope.resetForm = function(form) {
  //Even when you use form = {} it does not work
  form.fieldA = null;
  form.fieldB = null;
  ///more fields
}
```

Or

```
$scope.resetForm = function(form) {
      //Even when you use form = {} it does not work
      angular.copy({},form);
    }
```

instead of:

```
$scope.resetForm = function(form) {
  $scope.form = {};
}
```

In your plunk, I see that you're not separating the view from the model. You should do it for separation of concerns and to avoid problems that might happen when you clear all the fields (including DOM form object's fields).

```
<form name="form2" ng-controller="SecondController">
      <label for="first_field">First Field</label>
      <input ng-model="form2Model.first_field" />
      <br />
      <label for="second_field">Second Field</label>
      <input ng-model="form2Model.second_field" />
      <br />

      <a href="#" ng-click="secondReset(form2Model)">Reset the form</a>
    </form>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/x4JAeXra1bP4cQjIBld0?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly it doesn't seem to work either. Also, if I do a console.log on the form it shows that it is calling the reset function twice. I'm not sure why it is doing that.

Comment: @sturoid: with the current code, I have no idea why it calls the `resetForm` twice, maybe that problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. The problem is that if I use this with multiple forms then I would have to account for all the fields passed with the form. Would it be possible to do a loop through each field and set them to null or something similar?

Comment: @sturoid: yes, this is also a solution. I just pointed the problem why you cannot reset the form.

Comment: @sturoid: I see that you've never accepted an answer. Please do it so that people know which solution solves the problem in the question.

Comment: Sorry I was trying out the solutions. Works great! I made a plunker with the solution at:
http://plnkr.co/edit/tR1cd3pFVJxLgPvAplae?p=preview

Comment: @Kahn TO I found a strange error on the solution. When the form is cleared, and inputs are typed into again, I see the following error in the console:
    Object #<FormController> has no method '$setDirty'
Do you know why it would do that?

Comment: @sturoid: I don't see that error, but you should separate the view from the model. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was exactly the problem. I will update the plunker.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
form.fieldA = undefined;
```

It works great for radio buttons and checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this  :
Deploy your function inside form button reset , in this way ...

```
<input type ="button" ng-click="Object.field1 = null; ObjectN.fieldN = null;"  value="Reset" />
```