# How to empty form inputs in angular js after submission

Tags: angularjs, forms

Hello amazing Stackoverflow Coders, Please how do I empty form inputs in angular Js after form submission.

below is my working code

```
$rootScope.sendNow = function () {
                            if ($rootScope.send_login.username.length < 1)
                                alert("Please enter username");
                            else if ($rootScope.send_login.password.length < 1)
                                alert("Please enter password");
                            else {

                                $http.post($rootScope.server_url + "post_Data", $rootScope.send_login)
                                        .success(function (response)
                                        {
                                            // on success
                                            $('#send_login.username').val('');
                                              $('#send_login.password').val('');

                                            toastr.success('Successful');

                                        }

                                        ).error(function (response)
                                {

                                    alert("sending failed");
                                });
                            }
                        };
```

My Form is here below

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" ng-value="send_login.username">

                            <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" ng-value="send_login.password">
<input type="button" ng-click="sendNow()" value="Send">
```

Unlike Ajax, I have tried this below but cannot get it to work

```
 $('#send_login.username').val('');
  $('#send_login.password').val('');
```

Comment: Use ng-model to bind your inputs to a scope variable fields, and set this variable to {}.

Comment: with angular you have to use the scope as @jb-nizet mentioned

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs form reset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865125/angularjs-form-reset)

Comment: Take a look in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865125/angularjs-form-reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `ng-model` in the input tag, like:

html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name">
<button ng-click="sendData()"> Send</button>
```

js (angularjs Controller):

```
$scope.sendData = function (item) {
    $scope.name = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to take every form field ng-modal as a property of a object, like you have taken in "send_login".
After form submission reinitialize this object send_login = {};
Every field will be reinitialize. and a undefined property doesn't create a error in angular.

You should avoid so much use of $rootScope in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `ng-value` to `ng-model` (to bind the angular variable to html input) and on ajax success clear the binded variable:

```
$http.post('...').success(function (response) {
    $rootScope.send_login = {};
});
```